# Can anybody explain me what is going on here in the below two lambda expressions? Why I am getting two different results?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string> finalResult1 = firstList.FindAll(o => !(secondList.Any(oo => oo.Equals(o))));

List<string> finalResult2 = firstList.FindAll(o => secondList.Any(oo => !(oo.Equals(o))));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just read it from left to right, linq is close to English:

```
firstList.FindAll(o => !(secondList.Any(oo => oo.Equals(o))))
```

Return all objects `o` from `firstList`, for which there is not any object in `secondList` that is equal to `o`.

```
firstList.FindAll(o => secondList.Any(oo => !(oo.Equals(o))))
```

Return all objects `o` from `firstList`, for which there is any object in `secondList`that is not equal to `o`.

**Edit:** Just as a side note,

```
secondList.Any(oo => oo.Equals(o))
```

is equivalent to

```
secondList.Contains(o)
```

so the first expression can be simplified to

```
firstList.FindAll(o => !secondList.Contains(o))
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
firstList.Except( secondList ).ToList()
```

(where the ToList only exists to match the return type of FindAll)

Answer (score 1):

Cause `!` change everything. `Any -> All` && `Equals -> !Equals`

So first expression looks like

```
List<string> finalResult1 = firstList.FindAll(o => secondList.All(oo => !oo.Equals(o)));
```